# Javascript popup message in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a bizarre situation. When a check box in user control is unchecked a popup message should display asking for yes or no. Created a function window.showmodaldialog that uses a "somex.htm"( which is already present in the folder the user control exists).

When I run the application and uncheck the check box it does not display any pop up. So I added a break point at the code (please see below) and ran the application which halts at break point.

Now I clicked on Quick watch and when I reevaluate it displays the pop up box and when I hit yes it retrieves true and when I hit no it retrieves false as expected. I don't understand why this is not working under normal situation. Please help me and thanks in advance

```
 result = window.showModalDialog("ReassignPrimary.htm", window, 'dialogWidth=258px;dialogHeight=70px;status=0;');
```

Comment: Paste your code where you assign the function to the checkbox checked/unchecked event....you want to show the popup when it is checked so i assume you are doing so

Comment: function ChangeIsPrimary(sender) {
//    
    rval = window.showModalDialog("ReassignPrimary.htm", window, 'dialogWidth=258px;dialogHeight=70px;status=0;');
    if (rval === true) { //do something
    

        } if(rval===false){//do something}
    }    

In my codebehind

chkPrimary.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "return ChangeIsPrimary(this);")